# Telerik controls gives error on design page but works

Tags: asp.net, telerik

[image]

Gives me this error on Design View but it works in Code View and in Code-behind.
Wat may be the reason? I have an old .dll of Telerik

I'm using Visual Studio 2010. I havent used any installation of Telerik.
I copy "Telerik.Web.UI.dll" into Bin directory then add reference to my project

I have only 1 dll ("Telerik.Web.UI.dll" ) do I need other dll's as well to be able to work on Design View

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must install Telerik controls to be able to use them in designer.